# IMAP connection broken (server response) Exchange server

Tags: php, ssl, exchange-server, imap

Hope anyone will solve this issue, haven't got this issue solved after so much research 
I'm getting this error

> [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (server response)

when trying to append the message that is sent through PhpMailer.

Everything is working fine until the message size is greater than 7~8 KB
but get this error when the size is greater than that provided with or without attachments.

```
imap_append($mbox,  '{1.exchange2013.livemail.co.uk:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}Sent' , $details);
```

where $mbox is imap connection stream,
'{1.exchange2013.livemail.co.uk:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}Sent' is the connecton string(folder) and
 $details=  $mail->getSentMIMEMessage();//Returned from PhpMailer
P.S When trying to run the same with Yahoo to append the sent mail with Yahoo account it works well. But all my efforts went in vein when tried with Exchange Server. Hope someone had the same issue and got a solution. Please Help..

Comment: Post the protocol exchange, please. Not just [CLOSED].

Comment: "[CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (server response)" is the error I'm getting when trying to append the message to Sent Folder of exchange server if the message size is greater than 7kb. $mbox is the Resource Id which I'm getting with imap_open()

Comment: That's the error you get from the library you're using. What is the SERVER telling you?

Comment: I'm not getting any response from server nor the message is getting appended to sent folder of exchange server when I'm getting this message

Comment: If you're not getting a response from the server, you might investigate why not. I tested  just now with "openssl s_client -connect 1.exchange2013.livemail.co.uk:993 -crlf" and the server responds to me.

Comment: what I think is that the server is not accepting the content if the size is more than 7kb.

Comment: Should be easy to test. openssl s_client -connect 1.exchange2013.livemail.co.uk:993 -crlf, then issue login and append.

Comment: may I know how to test in which way you are saying ?

Comment: You issue the command "openssl s_client -connect 1.exchange2013.livemail.co.uk:993 -crlf", which gives you an IMAP prompt. At that prompt, you type IMAP, as described in RFC 3501. If you're going to develop an IMAP client knowing IMAP will be rather helpful for you.

Comment: Sorry sir I'm unable to get you as I have referred imap from - http://in3.php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php and I have coded entirely referring to it..

Comment: Well, if you want to debug the interaction between your code and Exchange, then you'll need to learn a little more than that. Also, in the future, please tag all PHP-related questions with the tag "php".